# Displaying Html form data using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

Hello there everybody i'm working on a simple javascript program in which it add and displays data from html form.Haven't faced any issues except for displaying the data.I've tried everything but failed can somebody help me with this.Here is the JS code for both add and display.

```
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
function AddressRegister(Name,Type,Address,Email,Mobile,Location)
{
this.Name = Name;
this.Type = Type;
this.Address = Address;
this.Email = Email;
this.Mobile = Mobile;
this.Location = Location;
}
var flag = 0;
var tabledata,button;
var dataArray = new Array();
function Add()
{
var Name=document.getElementById("name").value;
var Types=document.getElementsByName("type");
for(i = 0; i < Types.length; i++) { 
    if(Types[i].checked) 
    var Type = Types[i].value; 
}
var Address=document.getElementById("address").value; 
var Email=document.getElementById("email").value;
var Mobile=document.getElementById("mobile").value;
var Location=document.getElementById("location").value;

var data = new AddressRegister(Name,Type,Address,Email,Mobile,Location);
dataArray.push(data);
displayAddress();
}
function displayAddress()
{
if(flag==0)
{
tabledata = "<table style='position: fixed; background-color:lightgrey; border: 1px solid black; 
border-collapse: collapse;  margin-top: 25px;' border = '1'><tr><th>Name</th><th>Type</th> 
<th>Address</th><th>Email</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Location</th></tr>";
}

for(i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++)
{
var tempname=dataArray[i].Name;
var temptype=dataArray[i].Type;
var tempaddress=dataArray[i].Address;
var tempemail=dataArray[i].Email;
var tempmobile=dataArray[i].Mobile;
var templocation=dataArray[i].Location;
}
//console.log(tabledata);
if(flag==0){   

document.getElementById("name").value = "";

document.getElementsByName("type").checked = false;

document.getElementById("address").value = "";

document.getElementById("email").value ="";

document.getElementById("mobile").value ="";

document.getElementById("location").value = "";
}
count=0;
}
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your entire `<script>` as the last element in the `<body>`.

Your code references elements, which are not yet rendered when your script is being parsed. Your `document.getElementById("name")` and other ones return `null`.

Alternatively, you can wrap your code in `DOMContentLoaded` event listener:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    // your code
});
```

If you do it through `DOMContentLoaded` event, you can keep your code in `<head>`, because it will wait until DOM is ready.